# split by "." using flatMap in Spark for a text file

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to split the text file using . as delimiter.

```
val rdd2=rdd1.flatMap(x=>x.split("."))
```

But its not working. I have also tried to use backslash() before . as . is a wild character in Linux. But still its not splitting.

Comment: try this val rdd2=rdd1.flatMap(x=>x.split("\\."))

Comment: please up vote if you accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give like below.

```
val rdd2=rdd1.flatMap(x=>x.split("\\."))
```